# Only one expression can be specified in the select list w

Tags: sql

I am having problem in part of my code anyway to do this
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. The update part is working but how to use insert into to calculate if  a condition is not meant it will insert.

```
IF
    /* CHECKLIST TO UPDATE*/
    (NOT EXISTS     
        (SELECT *
        FROM    ENERGY.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE D_ENERGY_REFERENCE
                ,ENERGY.D_CHECK_LIST D_CHECK_LIST
        WHERE   D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.ID = D_CHECK_LIST.ID
        AND     D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.REFERENCE = 19051


        )
)

BEGIN 

INSERT INTO DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE(ID, REFERENCE_NO, REFERENCE,VALUE_INTEGER)
(SELECT ID, 
                (SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(REFERENCE_NO), 0) + 1 FROM DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE),
                19051,  (SELECT D_CHECK_LIST.ID,
      CASE 
        WHEN CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  NOT IN (0,1) THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE
        (
          CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  IN (2, 3, 50001, 50003, 50004, 50005, 50006, 50020, 50027, 50028) THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT)
            /
            CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  NOT IN (0,1) THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT)
        ) * 100 


    END  FROM DB.D_CHECK_LIST

     GROUP BY D_CHECK_LIST.ID) 

FROM DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE D_ENERGY_REFERENCE
WHERE  D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.ID = ID AND D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.REFERENCE = 19051
GROUP BY D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.ID
)

END
```

Comment: Tag appropriate database with your question. What difficulties you are facing?

Comment: This is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , it is SQL embeeded in a product for risk management

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this following part in the sub query of your script-

```
.......
19051,    
(
    SELECT 
    D_CHECK_LIST.ID, -- This is the column 1
    CASE 
        WHEN -- Here you are generating column 2 in the sub query
        ......
)
```

Here you are selecting 2 column - one is "D_CHECK_LIST.ID" and other one is generation through CASE WHEN statement. I think you should SELECT any 1 column from those 2 column. If both are required, you can use separate Sub query for that.

The ERROR code "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS" is self explanatory that you can not implement a Sub Query with more than 1 column selected unless the Sub Query is using inside EXISTS method.